# Traversing an unordered list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, traversal

This should be an easy one, but I'm not finding much online:

I have an unordered list `<ul>`, with a few list items underneath it `<li>`, and I'd like to address each one in the list, and act on it. How can I do this using jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) for this.

E.g.

```
$('ul#id li').each(function(index, element) {
    var li = $(element);
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I think you meant to link to the core `each()` - http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each as opposed to the utility function `each()` :)

Comment: Yes, found that out a sec after :)

Comment: I think you want only the immediate li children, as it may be nested.  That means `$('ul#id > li').each(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Something close to this:

```
$('#myulid').children('li').each(function(i, n) { alert($(this).html()); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code and change id as appropriate.

```
$("ul#id_of_desired_ul > li").each(function() {
   //do stuff
   // $(this) references each li
});
```

Comment: I think you want only the immediate li children, as it may be nested. That means `$('ul#id > li').each(...)`